WPF program sometimes has touch failure, but the mouse can click
WPF program uses a touch-screen all-in-one machine, so you can click on the screen or click with the mouse. When you start the program, everything is normal. After using it for a while, there is a small probability that you can't touch the screen, but you can click with the mouse. I really don't know why and how to solve it. I use the .netFramework framework。
I'm hoping someone who has experienced a similar situation can help me figure out the problem and fix it, as I can find very little information about it online.

I always implement the following method in app.xaml.cs when developing for touch screens in WPF:
private void DisableWPFTabletSupport()
{
    // Get a collection of the tablet devices for this window.
    TabletDeviceCollection devices = System.Windows.Input.Tablet.TabletDevices;

    if (devices.Count > 0)
    {
        // Get the Type of InputManager.  
        Type inputManagerType = typeof(System.Windows.Input.InputManager);

        // Call the StylusLogic method on the InputManager.Current instance.  
        object stylusLogic = inputManagerType.InvokeMember("StylusLogic",
                    BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null, InputManager.Current, null);

        if (stylusLogic != null)
        {
            //  Get the type of the stylusLogic returned from the call to StylusLogic.  
            Type stylusLogicType = stylusLogic.GetType();

            // Loop until there are no more devices to remove.  
            while (devices.Count > 0)
            {
                // Remove the first tablet device in the devices collection.  
                stylusLogicType.InvokeMember("OnTabletRemoved",
                        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                        null, stylusLogic, new object[] { (uint)0 });
            }
        }

    }
}

Maybe this will help?

So,does it work?I found lots of information about this framework on the Internet and found that it was flawed.

It's not perfect., but I think it makes more controls behave like you would expect them to.

I use the Click event on the touch screen. Is it effective in this case?
